# how to select plain HTML-text in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Does anyone of you know how to select plain HTML-text in CSS?

I have the following structure:

```
       <div id="A">
       <p class="caption"> caption1 </p>

        <div class="tabs">
             <div class='moving_bg'></div>

             <p class="text tab_item"> content</p>
             <p class="text tab_item"> content</p>
             <p class="text tab_item"> content</p>
             <p class="text tab_item"> content</p>
             <p class="text tab_item"> content</p>
             <p class="text tab_item"> content</p>

             caption2

             <p class="standardtext tab_item">content</p>
             <p class="standardtext tab_item"> content</p>
             <p class="standardtext tab_item"> content</p>


        </div>
```

How do I select the `caption2` in CSS?

As soon as I assign a class or a p-tag to it, it breakes the structure of the tab-plugin I'm using.

**Edit:**
I used [this](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/animated-tabbed-content-with-jquery/) plugin and changed it a little bit into:

```
var TabbedContent = {
init: function() {  
    $(".tab_item").mouseover(function() {

        var background = $(this).parent().find(".moving_bg");

        $(background).stop().animate({
            top: $(this).position()['top']
        }, {
            duration: 300
        });

        TabbedContent.slideContent($(this));

    });
},

slideContent: function(obj) {

    var margin =      $(obj).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".slide_content").width();
    margin = margin * ($(obj).prevAll().size() - 1);
    margin = margin * -1;

        $(obj).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".tabslider").stop().animate({
        marginLeft: margin + "px"
    }, {
        duration: 300
    });
}
}

$(document).ready(function() {
TabbedContent.init();
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't. You can only select elements and [pseudo-elements/classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-elements).

You might be able to get away with styling `.tabs` and then overriding the styles on `.tabs > *`.

> As soon as I assign a class or a p-tag to it, it breakes the structure of the tab-plugin I'm using.

Edit the plugin then.

Comment: Thanks, that was a fairly quick response :O. What would be the best way to style the caption in CSS? Should I just put the `caption2` somewhere outside, where I can assign a tag to it and force it via an abosolute position where I want it?

Comment: No. Breaking the logical structure of a document and then using absolute positioning to fake-put-it-back-together is never a good idea. Use appropriate markup and edit any existing code that can't cope with it.

Comment: I wanted to keep it less complex at first, but maybe it would be better to change the jquery plugin. I used [this](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/animated-tabbed-content-with-jquery/) plugin and changed it a little bit as you can see in my edited post above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `*` selector at the top of your CSS. It will initially style all elements on your page, even plain text, and then apply the rules for the rest of your selectors.

**NOTE**: This selector is known to be slow, and you will have to override any problematic rules in it. (Check [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net))

```
* {
    font-size: 13px;
    color:red
}
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.tabs { foo:bar; jim:jam }
.tabs > * { foo:original; jim:original } /* Every child element of tabs */
```

This requires you to know what the inherited/original values are, likely re-specifying styles already declared, but it will work.

If this is a prohibitive number of styles, you could modify your rules like:

```
#a, #a .tabs > * { ...many styles applying generally ... }
.tabs { ...specific styles for just this element... }
```

The specificity rules of CSS will cause the rules you specify specifically for the child elements to take precedence over those specified on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select it as part of `<div class="tabs">` so

```
div.tabs{
    /* whatever */
}
```

as it exists in that `div`.

You may need overwrite some styles in the `p.tab_item`

Comment: That would also select all other elements inside of the div.

Comment: Exactly @Truth. But then you can override the styles in the subsequent `p`s.

Comment: Yeah, but what If I chose an element with 20 different elements? I would then need a very large rule, or worse, 20 different rules. The fact is, one can't select a text node in CSS. There's no point try to hack it.

Comment: Depending on where the code comes from, sometimes hacks are necessary.  In this case, I would style the entire `div` and then restyle the child `p`s.  Looks to be no more than 3 rules.